# Android app not working on HTC Desire but working fine on other devices

Tags: exception, android

My Android application works fine on Samsung Galaxie S2 , MotoDroid, ZTE Blade and the android simulator but crashes on HTC Desire.
When I debug my code on HTC Desire, it throws `Resource Not found` exception in the `SetContentView(R.layout.splash_screen_layout);`
I have deleted and regenerated the Gen folder, but to no avail , the issue was only reproduced on the HTC Device, so far.

Here's the LogCat:

```
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.relay.BA/com.relay.BA.SplashScreen}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030010
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2781)
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2797)
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2132)
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030010
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:892)
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1869)
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731)
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1654)
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630):     at com.relay.BA.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:43)
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1065)
01-06 05:32:58.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2745)
```

Has anyone experienced this issue or has any idea what's going on?

Comment: whats the app you developing.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost surely the case that the layouts you declare in one of your `layout-*` folders is correct, but another is not, and referring to non-existent IDs or something like that. So, on one device, perhaps it uses `layout-large` and is fine, but on another device, it uses `layout-normal` or something like that and fails.

Comment: Yeah...I have layouts only in my layout-normal folder and kept the others empty for the time-being (I was keeping the UI changes for the end :)) I'll work on it and let you know

Comment: Also, I had tried the app on HVGA, WVGA and QVGA simulators where it also worked fine. I figured that by default, it will pick up the normal layouts...

Answer (score 0):

**try removing your `SDCard` and mount it Again.**

this trick has worked for me many times on different devices when i failed to install or launch any of my application.